# Using Koa, how do I get post variables

Tags: koa

Let's say I want o get a simple variable posted to a Koa app without using an extension, how would I do it?

Comment: Within middleware/handler, `this.request` gives you access to the Koa request. But `this.req` gives you access to the underlying raw Node request which has all the information you need. You generally use middleware to parse `this.req`, format it, and move it into `this.request` for consumption by your app. So check out the plain ol `this.req`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the official [`koa-bodyparser`](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser) module.

Then all the `POST` parameters will be available in `this.request.body`.

---

From the docs:

```
app.use(function *() {
  // the parsed body will store in this.request.body
  // if nothing was parsed, body will be an empty object {}
  this.body = this.request.body;
});
```